# unable to import Selenium2library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium2library

Here is the details

Log:     C:\Users\t681826\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\venv\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\t681826\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\venv\report.html
PS C:\Users\t681826\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\venv> robot C:\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\TestCases\TC_NM.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\TestCases\TC_NM.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Selenium2Library
Traceback (most recent call last):
None
PYTHONPATH:
C:\Program Files\choco\python-27\Python27\Scripts\robot.exe
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\python27.zip
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\DLLs
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\lib
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\lib\plat-win
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\lib\lib-tk
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27
c:\program files\choco\python-27\python27\lib\site-packages
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\UBS\Dev\tenable\tenable_sc_nm_automation\Resources\PageObjects\KeywordDefinationFiles\LoginPage.robot' on line 3: Importing library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Selenium2Library
Traceback (most recent call last):
None

want to import Selenium2Library.

Already installed interpreter in pycharm. Robotframework